# Are there drawbacks to using destsz = sizeof(dst) for strncpy_s()?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, strncpy

I'm working off this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy

The function header is described as this:

```
errno_t strncpy_s(char *restrict dest, rsize_t destsz, const char *restrict src, rsize_t count);
```

Is there any significant drawback other than speed, to setting `destsz = sizeof(dest)` ?

Comment: Yes, it is a bug.  You want to know the size of the buffer, not the size of a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to use `strncpy_s` like this

```
strncpy_s(dest, sizeof(dest), src, sizeof(src));
```

This assumes that `dest` and `src` are expressions representing an array variable, like this.

```
char a[3];
char b[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
strncpy_s(a, sizeof(a), b, sizeof(b));
```

If instead, `dest` or `src` were pointers (for example, `char*`), like this.

```
char* ptr1 = a;
char* ptr2 = b;
strncpy_s(ptr1, sizeof(ptr1), ptr2, sizeof(ptr2));
```

The code would compile, but the values would be wrong, because `sizeof(ptr1)` would be the size of the pointer object, not the size of the array. In that case, you would have to provide the size in some other way

So, no direct drawbacks, but using this pattern can be error prone.

As suggested by @Alex, when using the Microsoft C Runtime Library, you can directly pass the array expression for the destination without passing the size separately

```
strncpy_s(a, ptr2, sizeof(b));
```

Then, providing the size is not necessary, and doing so brings nothing except potentially mixing up an array and a pointer. For example, if one accidentally writes `strncpy_s(ptr1, b, sizeof(b))`, the code would not compile, rather than work with the wrong values

Answer (score 1):

No, in fact the template overloads for `strncpy_s` do exactly that when you provide a fixed width array as the destination parameter. However, `sizeof(dest)` will not work if `dest` is a pointer type, as the size of a pointer is always the size of the native machine word (32 or 64 bit). If you have a pointer, you will need to keep track of the allocated size in a second variable.

Comment: what template overloads?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Likely the [Microsoft ones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strncpy-s-strncpy-s-l-wcsncpy-s-wcsncpy-s-l-mbsncpy-s-mbsncpy-s-l?view=vs-2019), but those didn't make it into the C standard obviously (being that they rely on C++ features).

Comment: Given that the question is tagged as Visual C++, the op is using MSVC. In MSVC's CRT there are C++ template overloads that deduce the size of the array parameter and provide that to the underlying function. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strncpy-s-strncpy-s-l-wcsncpy-s-wcsncpy-s-l-mbsncpy-s-mbsncpy-s-l?view=vs-2019.